# Move multiple files to directories in linux

Tags: linux, file, directory, copy, move

I have a directory structure like this;

```
dir
├── dirA
│   └── file1
│   └── subdir
└── dirB
    └── file2
    └── subdir
```

I need to move file1 to subdir1 and file2 to subdir2.
How can I do it in Linux?

Comment: Is there some actual structure to the names that allows a bigger change?  If not, why not just do `mv dirA/file1 dirA/subdir1; mv dirB/file2 dirB/subdir2`?

Comment: @WilliamPursell Because there are 36920 directories and files under them. I need to find a faster way for working with them. This is just a prototype for the problem.

Comment: So tell us what the structure is.  Otherwise, we are guessing.

Comment: Do you have 36920 directories, all of which contain exactly one file (with an arbitrary name) and one directory (also with an arbitrary name)?  Or do you have a bunch of directories that contain many files, and you want to move one that has a particular name?  Or...there are a lot of possibilities.

Comment: I have 36920 subdirs with different names like dirA, dirB, dirC....
Also, I have different files under them like file1, file2, file3..... under these subdirs. And have subdir with same name under these different subdirs.
I need to move files to subdir.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with this;

```
$ for dir in dir/*/; do mv dir/*/file* "$dir/subdir"; done
```

Comment: But, I'm not sure this is the best solution. Please, try it or suggest me better one.

Comment: Looks good. you can use above mentioned command .

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple bash script.
below is the sample directory tree structure.

```
tree 
.
|-- dir-2
|   |-- file-1
|   |-- file2
|   |-- file3
|   |-- file4
|   `-- subdir
|-- dir-3
|   |-- file-1
|   |-- file2
|   |-- file3
|   |-- file4
|   `-- subdir
|-- dir-4
|   |-- file-1
|   |-- file2
|   |-- file3
|   |-- file4
|   `-- subdir
```

run the below script from the parent directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
ls -d */ > out.txt
for i in `cat out.txt` ; do

ls -l $i
cd $i
mv * subdir/ 
cd .. 
   
done;
```

tree structure after executing the above script.

```
$ tree 
.
|-- dir-2
|   `-- subdir
|       |-- file-1
|       |-- file2
|       |-- file3
|       `-- file4
|-- dir-3
|   `-- subdir
|       |-- file-1
|       |-- file2
|       |-- file3
|       `-- file4
|-- dir-4
|   `-- subdir
|       |-- file-1
|       |-- file2
|       |-- file3
|       `-- file4
```